# How to output a Tab delimated file in a particular format

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please how do you output data to a new or existing file in columns, I tried creating a list and using .append() with variables but that did not work 
the data is meant to look like :

```
ABC. DEF. GHI. JKL.
```

here is my code so far:

```
try:
    first_input = raw_input('Enter Filename:')
    data = first_input
    openfile = open(data,'r')
    openfile = open(data,'a')
    author = raw_input('Enter Author Name:')
    title = raw_input('Enter Title Name:')
    year= raw_input('Enter year:')
    Journal = raw_input('Enter Journal:')
except IOError:
    openfile = open(data,'a')
    author = raw_input('Enter Author Name:')
    title = raw_input('Enter Title Name:')
    year= raw_input('Enter year:')
    Journal = raw_input('Enter Journal:)
```

output should be tab delimited and look like :

```
author. title. year. journal    with the '.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need use the csv module, specifying the delimiter as a `tab` with `delimiter="\t"` and add a period to each string:

```
import csv
first_input = raw_input('Enter Filename:')
data = first_input
author = raw_input('Enter Author Name:')
title = raw_input('Enter Title Name:')
year= raw_input('Enter year:')
Journal = raw_input('Enter Journal:')

with open(data,"a") as f: 
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\t")
    wr.writerow([author+".",title+".",year+".",Journal+"."])
```

Input:

```
Enter Filename:test.csv
Enter Author Name:foo
Enter Title Name:foobar
Enter year:2015
Enter Journal:foobar
```

test.csv:

```
foo.    foobar. 2015.   foobar.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want exactly,
 but let me see.
to open and write to file(or append existing) use 'a' parameter in open() function. You should use with construction when working with file-streams:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as my_file:
    my_file.write('anything you want as string')
my_file.close()
```

another point is to have string consists of values separated by tab:

```
val_1 = 'Name'
val_2 = 'Age'
val_3 = 'Yes'
```

First of all you need to create a list and get this values as list members(instead of assigning it to string variables):

```
my_list = []
my_list.append('Name')
my_list.append('Age')
my_list.append('Yes')
```

afterwards create sting from list and indicate you want separate values with tab:

```
'\t'.join(my_list)
```

this will create sting: 'Name    Age    Yes'

Combine this knowledge to make your own code. and don't hesitate to use additional resources to get more info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: You're creating `my_list` in an incorrect way. I also think you have a typo: `may_list`.

Comment: why it's incorrect? Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I meant assign values to list members not to string variables. my_list[0] = raw_input('enter value')

Comment: Have you tried running the code? I'm getting "IndexError: list assignment index out of range".

Comment: You can also create a list with all the elements i.e. `my_list = ['Name', 'Age', 'Yes']`.